# How to handle two options for the SELECT in a for loop

Tags: postgresql

I have the following code in a function...

```
CREATE FUNCTION blah(
    p_task_id                 INTEGER
)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
DECLARE
    v_name                    CHAR(30);
    v_age                     INTEGER;
    v_select_string           TEXT;
BEGIN
    ...

        IF v_name = '' AND v_age = 0 THEN
            v_select_string =  'SELECT * FROM my_table
                                    WHERE id = p_id';
        ELSE
            v_select_string =  'SELECT * FROM my_table 
                                    WHERE name = ' || v_name || '
                                    AND   age  = ' || v_age  || '
                                    AND   id   = p_id';
        END IF;

        FOR s1 IN (
            v_select_string
                )
        LOOP

            ...

        END LOOP;
```

... but I'm getting this...

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "v_select_string"
```

Is there any way of fixing this? The contents of the loop are huge, so I'd rather not duplicate the loop in the `IF / ELSE`

Comment: Did you mean to dynamically execute the sql? Or did you try to loop over a string?

Comment: @bergi I want to execute the query

Comment: Unrelated, but: [don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just pass a string to a FOR loop. You need to run it as [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING) using the `execute` keyword.

```
FOR s1 IN EXECUTE v_select_string
LOOP
  ...
END LOOP;
```

Comment: I love you! Ahem, sorry about that... That's just the ticket, many thanks :)